# Design of "simple" 1000W AC motor/ heating element controller

Tags: triac

I have been working on designing a circuit which can reliable control the on/off cycles of a 1000W (vacuum cleaner) Motor and a 1000W Cartridge heating element. It should be noted that the motor and heating element both have an separate circuit. The circuit is as follows:

[image: current circuit design]

It works as follows:

- The circuit is designed for 230V Mains
- A micro-controller (ATMega328) will detect the zero crossing of the grid and decide whether to turn the motor/ heating element on or off for the following period.
- If the triac must be fired, PD4 will be pulled to high, triggering the photo triac, which will trigger the BTA208S-800E Triac.
- The snubber networks consisting of the resistors/ capacitors are supposed to protect the Triacs from misfiring.

Though, there are a few unanswered questions I would like to ask: First, the motor causes a lot of noise on the grid, does the snubber filter this unwanted EMI or would it need separate filtering (what/how)?

In the datasheet of the BTA208S-800E I found that the thermal resistance from junction to ambient is: 75K/W. How do you calculate the amount of Watts dissipated in the Triac? I plan on using a copper ground plane as heat sink.

Most European wall outlets have 2 pins for the power and a separate for earth. Can I connect the earth wire to the enclosure where both the heating element and motor are placed in?

Last, I would like to detect if the motor is not malfunctioning (if it is, both the heating element and motor should be shut down). I was wondering if detecting this would be possible by monitoring the back EMF caused by the motor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking quite a few questions. I'll answer the one about calculating heat sinks and power dissipation for a triac such as the BT208. First, to determine the power dissipation refer to the [datasheet](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/BTA208S-800B.pdf).

[image]

From the RMS current you can find the power dissipation. Since you're not doing phase control, \$\alpha\$ = 180°. So if the motor draws 4A RMS, the power dissipation will be about 5.2W maximum. Note that this says nothing about watts in the load, it's load *current* that makes the triac heat.

**If** (and it's an important **if**) your mounting is the same as the quoted mounting (size of copper pad and so on) and you achieve 75°C/W then you can calculate the temperature rise. Also pay attention to figure 1 that tells you that you should not let the heatsink temperature get much beyond 100°C and the absolute maximum junction temperature of 125°C. Conservative design would keep well below those numbers even on a very hot day. So if your ambient could be 60°C inside the enclosure, and you allowed the heat sink to get to 90°C, then you could allow 30°C rise, or about 2.5W, so it's good for about 3A (with those assumptions).

Comment: If the triac heatsink could be placed in the pre-heated airflow from the fan, would it be sensible to monitor the temperature of the triac to determine if the fan motor is working?

Comment: You want to keep the triac as cool as possible. You could suck air over the triac heatsink before it goes to the heater.